# Not interested in LED lighting

Tags: lighting

I would like to buy a ceiling fan that says it has an led light. Can I use an incandescent light bulb in place of the led?

Comment: Possibly but some modification may be needed.

Comment: Whether you can or not depends on many details you haven't shared here. Please provide information about the exact make and model of the ceiling fan, and any electrical specifications given for the fan, whether found in instruction sheets, product packaging, or on the fan itself.

Comment: All that said, there's really no point in hating on LED lights. When operating correctly, modern LED lights are superior to incandescent bulbs in every way. And especially for a ceiling fan, I would think that the vastly longer life of the LED light would be of particular importance and benefit, not to mention the fraction of electricity they consume.

Comment: Why do you *not* want a LED light?

Comment: @PeterDuniho one counter argument is that incandescents dim much more gracefully and glowfully than LEDs, and that could be enough to tip the OP.

Comment: for instance w/this fan?      https://www.overstock.com/Lighting-Ceiling-Fans/Prominence-Home-Snowden-Farmhouse-Aged-Bronze-52-inch-LED-Ceiling-Fan-with-Linen-Drum-Light/22344432/product.html?TID=Cart:Link:ProductLink:CartItems

Comment: @P2000: FWIW, it really depends on the LED. This was a huge problem with the early LED lamps, even when a proper CFL/LED-compatible dimmer was installed. But my experience in the last few years has been that the dimming is equal to incandescent bulbs now. Even at the lowest settings, the duty cycle frequency is high enough to avoid annoying flickering, and the dimming control is stable, addressing the two most common issues of the early iterations. Granted, you can still find cheap LED stuff that still has those problems, but it doesn't cost _that_ much to get lamps that work right.

Answer (score 4):

### LEDs don't need sockets

Most "has LED" fans and such have *integrated LED fixtures* which are entirely bulbless.  Remember when televisions and radios had tubes?  People had to open up their TV or radio all the time to change burned out tubes.   Then, they went to transistors, which are so reliable they just solder them to the board (they are more reliable *than the socket*).

LEDs are a semiconductor just like a transistor, and are *that* reliable - they are not a bulb, and will outlive us all.  (the electronic driver that regulates current to them might not, however). **As such, there's really no reason for an LED fixture to have any sockets at all**.

### The issue with incandescents is *thermal*

Even if you find a way,  you can't just switcheroonie any given LED fixture over to incandescent.  The reason is, incandescents make **a lot of heat** and *having that heat **not** burn your house down* is the #1 design factor in any incandescent fixture.   LED fixtures don't give this any thought, so they are unsuitable for incandescent bulbs.

As always, it's better to buy what you want, instead of buying what you don't want and hacking it. There should be loads of new and used fans that are made for real incandescents.  Just buy those.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can, mostly these days you can't.

It depends very specifically on the model of the fan, and if not clearly labeled "Max 60W" or so (ok), in stead of say "MAX 7W LED" (no ok), you'd have to check with the manufacturer. Do not assume that it is safe to just replace the bulb, even if it fits. It could become a fire hazard due to heat development around the bulb and in the wiring.

Alternatively you can look on sites for used electrical house hold items (craigslist, facebook, kijiji come to mind) to look or ask for an old one, often for free. Again check the labeling. With anything older than 10 years, maybe even 5, you more are likely to find what you need.